# error `1"" was unexpected at this time.` when first command line argument is double quoted

Tags: batch-file

Running the following minimal example:

```batch
(
    echo if "%%1" == "" (
    echo   echo Success ^|^| goto :fail
    echo ^) else (
    echo   echo Failure ^|^| goto :fail
    echo ^)
) >"testresult.bat"

call "testresult.bat" "first 1" --flag="other options" --verbose
```

Results the following as contents of `testresult.bat`:

```batch
if "%1" == "" (
  echo Success || goto :fail
) else (
  echo Failure || goto :fail
)
```

And calling `testresult.bat` with the command line arguments `"first 1" --flag="other options" --verbose` gives me:

```
C:\User>test.bat

C:\User>(
echo if "%1" == "" (
 echo   echo Success || goto :fail
 echo ) else (
 echo   echo Failure || goto :fail
 echo )
) 1>"testresult.bat"

C:\User>call "testresult.bat" "first 1" --flag="other options" --verbose
1"" was unexpected at this time.

C:\User>if ""first 1"" == "" (

C:\User>
```

The error `1"" was unexpected at this time.` is caused because my first arguments has a double quotes.

How can I properly write my `if "%1" == ""` to check whether the first argument is empty, regardless it has double quotes or not?

Comment: Have you tried `if "%~1"==""` (note the `~`)? See [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)...

Comment: I did not. It worked thanks! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is referencing argument 1 with `"%1"` instead of `"%~1"`.

The help output on running in a Windows command prompt window `call /?` explains that `%1` references the first argument as passed to the batch file without or with being enclosed in double quotes.

For that reason passing the string `"first 1"` as first argument to the created batch file results in an **IF** condition with `""first 1""` left to comparison operator `==` which is a serious syntax error on the **IF** condition.

The usually used solution is using `"%~1"` on **IF** command line. The modifier `~` results in removing surrounding `"` from first argument string if there are surrounding double quotes at all. So the first string on **IF** condition is now **nearly** always correct enclosed with one pair of double quotes.

The batch file can be called with `if "%~1" == ""` with first argument being:

1. `argument1` ... not quoted argument string because of `"` not necessary.
2. `"argument 1"` ... quoted argument string because of space character.
3. `""` ... empty string as argument string.
   The condition is true although the batch file is run with an argument string. Most batch files requiring one or more argument strings do not allow that one of the argument strings is an empty string. But some batch scripts support also empty argument strings.
4. `"argument 1` ... not correct quoted argument string with space character working nevertheless on using `%~1` as the single `"` at beginning is removed in this case.
5. `argument1"` ... not correct quoted argument string.
   Windows command processor does not remove `"` at end of the not correct specified argument string resulting in a syntax error on command line `if "%~1" == ""` because of resulting command line is `if "argument1"" == ""`.

See my answer on [What is the difference between "…" and x"…" in an IF condition in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418905/3074564) It explains in detail how to write a batch file which works even on last argument example.